# Match any number BUT positive 1-10

Tags: regex

I've tried the following without any success

```
^((\d{1,})\b[^1-10]\b)$
```

What should match:
"11", "0", "-1", "100" and any number which is not 1-9

What shouldn't match:
"10", "1", "abc11", "11abc", "a11b" and any number >= 1 AND <= 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want

```
^(?!(?:[1-9]|10)$)-?\d+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/46Gmd2/1/). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!(?:[1-9]|10)$)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a digit from `1` to `9` or `10` substring followed with end of string position immediately to the right of the current location
- `-?` - an optional `-`
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `$` - end of string.

If you cannot use lookarounds, you can use

```golang
^(-[0-9]+|0|1[1-9]|[2-9][0-9]|[0-9]{3,})$
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/46Gmd2/3). This regex matches:

- `^` - start of string
- `(` - start of a capturing group:

  - `-[0-9]+|` - `-` and then one or more digits, or
  - `0|` - `0`, or
  - `1[1-9]|` - `1` and then a non-zero digit, or
  - `[2-9][0-9]|` - a digit from `2` to `9` and then any one digit, or
  - `[0-9]{3,}` - any three or more digits
- `)` - end of the group
- `$` - end of string

Comment: I'm getting error "invalid perl operator: (?!"

Comment: @Pixy Is it RE2 library you are using?

Comment: It's for an IBM Watson bot pattern, I don't know what they're using

Comment: @Pixy Check the second solution.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is not very elegant, but should match the data and rules you posted:

```
^((-1|0)|(\d{2,}))$
```

> **Mini description of the parts of the expression:**
>
> - ^ Start of string
> - (-1|0) the two "edge case" *(Yes, hardcoded)*
> - (\d{2,}) atleast two digits
> - $ end of string
> - *(,) just grouping, to*